# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSBJSON", referenced from:

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

i have a try to run the application and application give me this error

if anyone know that then please provide solution

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSBJSON", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611410/undefined-symbols-and-duplicate-symbols-errors-can-build-for-debug-or-release

Comment: no it's not helpful i already check this link

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible things due to which this error may come:

1. while adding the SBJSON you might not be checked that copy option .
2. or go to compiled sources and see your .m file is specified there or not .